Issues compiling react native extension using fbjni & C++
I am in the process of developing a react native extension that makes use of C++ STD::THREAD and using facebook jni, unfortunately I haven't been able to get my app to compile with my extension, I've spent a ton of time trying to change fbjni versions, I've tried 0.2.2 and 0.3.0 and 0.6.0 and all of them I have the same errors which seem to be internal to fbjni?
Here are the errors im seeing
 /home/computer/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/8ed03866ffab8cdaec37a63d4e51c42d/transformed/fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/detail/Registration-inl.h:165:47: error: no member named 'kDescriptor' in 'facebook::jni::jmethod_traits_from_cxx<void (long)>' return jmethod_traits_from_cxx<R(Args...)>::kDescriptor;
 In file included from /home/computer/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/8ed03866ffab8cdaec37a63d4e51c42d/transformed/fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/detail/CoreClasses-inl.h:25: /home/computer/.gradle/caches/8.8/transforms/8ed03866ffab8cdaec37a63d4e51c42d/transformed/fbjni-0.3.0/prefab/modules/fbjni/include/fbjni/detail/Meta.h:370:29: error: no matching function for call to 'JMethodDescriptor' static constexpr decltype(internal::JMethodDescriptor<void, Args...>()) /* detail::SimpleFixedString */ kConstructorDescriptor = internal::JMethodDescriptor<void, Args...>();
This points to this line in my module.cpp file , In file included from /home/computer/Projects/ReactNativeWorkerBeeDemo/node_modules/react-native-workerbee/android/src/main/jni/WorkerBeeModule.cpp:3:
line 3 looks like this
https://github.com/austinksmith/react-native-workerbee/blob/master/android/src/main/jni/WorkerBeeModule.cpp#L3
and my cmakelis.txt looks like this..
https://github.com/austinksmith/react-native-workerbee/blob/master/android/CMakeLists.txt
You can view an example application to see these compilation errors from this repo
https://github.com/austinksmith/ReactNativeWorkerBeeDemo
I am not extremely skilled in C++ so I might be doing something wrong in my jni files?
https://github.com/austinksmith/react-native-workerbee/blob/master/android/src/main/jni/worker-jsi.cpp
I tried taking a look at another project that uses JNI and STD::THREAD as well, however this extension was built for react native before 0.71 and it manually links packages in the cmakelists.txt file, manually linking the files didn't help me and according to a readme i found in the react native node_modules folder, you aren't supposed to manually extract AAR files anymore.
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, the full source code for the demo and the extension are available in the links above.
Referencing the react native documentation, checking google, asking claude.ai, asking chatgpt4, searching fbjni facebook repo issues, referencing setup of an existing react native extension using similar libraries, hours of trying different versions of fbjni.
